# Setting a custom font size for part of the document that frequently uses size-specific commands like \large and \huge

Tags: fontsize

For my thesis I'm using a popular template ([MasterDoctoralThesis](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)) that comes with a beautiful title page. I have to adhere to APA guidelines of 12 pt text and onehalf spacing, which are not the default settings for this template, and it stretches the content to almost 2 full pages.

Is there a way to make just this title page use 11 pt font and single spacing? Font size seems to have the largest impact, as using the `singlespacing` environment from the `setspace` package leads to little change. Changing the manually applied spaces in the code to make it all fit on one page makes everything look cramped, sadly. Using something like `\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont` inside the `center` block had no effect.

The MWE below generates a mock-up page of how the design is supposed to look. You can simulate the problem by changing the font size to 12 pt and the `singlespacing` block to `onehalfspacing`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    paper=a4paper,
    inner=1in,
    outer=1in,
    bindingoffset=.5cm,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
    \begin{singlespacing}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{.06\textheight}
            {\scshape\LARGE UNIVERSITY NAME\par}\vspace{1.5cm}
            \textsc{\Large THESIS TYPE}\\[0.5cm]
        
            \rule{.9\linewidth}{.6pt} \\ [0.4cm]
            {\huge \bfseries LONG\\ THESIS\\ TITLE\par}\vspace{0.4cm}
            \rule{.9\linewidth}{.6pt} \\[1.5cm]
        
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \begin{flushleft} \large
                    \emph{Author:}\\
                    AUTHOR NAME
                \end{flushleft}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
                \begin{flushright} \large
                    \emph{First supervisor:} \\
                    FIRST SUPERVISOR\\
                    INSTITUTE, CITY \\ \bigskip\bigskip
                    \emph{Second supervisor:} \\
                    SECOND SUPERVISOR\\
                    UNIVERSITY, CITY
                \end{flushright}
            \end{minipage}\\[3cm]
        
            \vfill
        
            \large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements\\ for the degree of DEGREE NAME}\\[0.3cm]
            \textit{in}\\[0.4cm]
            SUBJECT NAME\\[2cm]
        
            \vfill
        
            {\large \today}\\[4cm]
        
            \vfill
        \end{center}
    \end{singlespacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear but probably you want to change `[11pt]` to `[12pt]` then in that title page just reduce the fonts one step so change `\huge` to `\LARGE`,  `\LARGE` to `\Large` and change `\Large` to `\large`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By applying the changes you suggested and reducing the manual spacing statements a little I got it to work. Shame there is no fontsize environment that works similar to the `singlespacing` environment. Just for future reference, what sort of clarity would you have wished for in the question? I thought I made my problem clear but apparently I missed something...

Comment: well maybe it was clear enough as I did apparently understand it, although I wasn't at all sure that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to change `[11pt]` to `[12pt]` then in that title page just reduce the fonts one step so change `\huge` to `\LARGE`, `\LARGE` to `\Large` and change `\Large` to `\large`, then adjust any explicit lengths such as  `\\[1.5cm]` to whatever looks tight for your new design.